# Google Maps - Infobox API - scroll pane vs change position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using Google Maps InfoBox - 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

Currently the map will scroll - pan control - when your infobox is outside of the bounds of the map.

I'm looking for a way to detect if the infobox will be outside of the bounds of the map, and if so the position is switched (currently I have the infoBoxAnchor set at 9,2) - so set the infoboxanchor in the opposite x direction.

Anyone done anything like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be tricky - infowindows are dynamically sized based on the content in them.  What you could do, is in the InfoWindowOptions, set `disableAutoPan=true`.  This will prevent the map panning to display the infowindow.  Then I'm guessing you could use jQuery (or any other JS you like) to figure out:

- the size of the infowindow based on the position where it's anchored to on the map,
- is the entire infowindow visible
- if not, move the infowindow's position

Answer (score 0):

Related:

- [Auto adjustment of InfoWindow position on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8017267/216084)
- [Google Maps Mashup with Intelligently positioning InfoBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10195469/216084)
- [Google Maps: How to prevent InfoWindow from shifting the map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2488999/216084)

And a possible solution (thanks to above links) at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html